# how to shuffle an array without involving the first element?

Tags: java, arrays, random, shuffle

Hi I wanna to shuffle a list and index 0 is fixed but another index has been changing and my list have data model class

```
sample =[Angelina Jolie.jpg, Ben Affleck.jpg, Bruce Willis.jpg, Michael Jackson.jpg, Miley Cyrus.jpg, Pharrell Williams.jpg, Rihanna.jpg, Ryan Gosling.jpg]

shuffled=[Angelina Jolie.jpg, Michael Jackson.jpg,Rihanna.jpg, Ryan Gosling.jpg, Miley Cyrus.jpg, Pharrell Williams.jpg, Ben Affleck.jpg, Bruce Willis.jpg ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are the array items Strings or Objects?

Comment: If they are objects, look here https://www.programcreek.com/2012/02/java-method-to-shuffle-an-int-array-with-random-order/

Comment: My guess is that your shuffling algorithm has an off-by-one error, but without looking at the code it's difficult to say.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to shuffle an array without involving the first element? Or are you asking us why your program doesn't shuffle the first element?

Comment: In either case, [edit] your question and include your code.

Comment: my english language is so bad i so sorry :(

Comment: You are doing great! We are used to much worse here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick example, using Lists:

```
String [] example = { "A", "B", "C", "D"};
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(example);
Collections.shuffle(items.subList(1, items.size()));
System.out.println(items);
```

The point is: you can create a **view** using the `sublist()` method, and shuffle that. And of course you can use the `toArray()` methods of the List interface to turn your list back into an array.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new list using sublist() and shuffle that, since the new sub list is backed by the main list the main list will be shuffled to (except the first element)

```
 List<String> subList = list.subList(1, list.size());
 Collections.shuffle(subList);
```

The original list is now shuffled from element 1 and onward.

Comment: @GhostCat your solution was a little more elegant without the temp variable, up-vote delivered.

Comment: You are very welcome ;-)